# TLS connection from Java client to mosquitto MQTT broker

Tags: java, ssl, mqtt, mosquitto

I am trying to set up a a tls connection to an mqtt mosquitto broker.
i generate keys and certificates following : https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-tls-7.html

then here is my code :

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String serverUrl = "ssl://129.6.60.24:8883";
        String caFilePath = "./src/main/resources/ca.crt";
        String clientCrtFilePath = "./src/main/resources/brokerCertificate.crt";
        String clientKeyFilePath = "./src/main/resources/ca.key";
        String mqttUserName = "cpcc";
        String mqttPassword = "1qaz!QAZ1qaz";
        MqttClient client;

        try {
            client = new MqttClient(serverUrl, "TestBedBroker");
            client.setCallback(new SimpleMqttCallBack());
            MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
            options.setUserName(mqttUserName);
            options.setPassword(mqttPassword.toCharArray());
            SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = SslUtil.getSocketFactory(caFilePath, clientCrtFilePath, clientKeyFilePath, "1qaz!QAZ1qaz");
            options.setSocketFactory(socketFactory);
            System.out.println("starting connect the server...");
            client.connect(options);
            System.out.println("connected!");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            client.disconnect();
            System.out.println("disconnected!");

        }
        catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public class SslUtil {
    public static SSLSocketFactory getSocketFactory(final String caCrtFile, final String crtFile, final String keyFile, final String password) throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        // load CA certificate
        X509Certificate caCert = null;

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(caCrtFile);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

        while (bis.available() > 0) {
            caCert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(bis);
            // System.out.println(caCert.toString());
        }

        // load client certificate
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(crtFile));
        X509Certificate cert = null;
        while (bis.available() > 0) {
            cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(bis);
            // System.out.println(caCert.toString());
        }

        // load client private key
        PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new FileReader(keyFile));
        Object object = pemParser.readObject();
        PEMDecryptorProvider decProv = new JcePEMDecryptorProviderBuilder().build(password.toCharArray());
        JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider("BC");
        KeyPair key;
        if (object instanceof PEMEncryptedKeyPair) {
            System.out.println("Encrypted key - we will use provided password");
            key = converter.getKeyPair(((PEMEncryptedKeyPair) object).decryptKeyPair(decProv));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Unencrypted key - no password needed");
            key = converter.getKeyPair((PEMKeyPair) object);
        }
        pemParser.close();

        // CA certificate is used to authenticate server
        KeyStore caKs = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        caKs.load(null, null);
        caKs.setCertificateEntry("ca-certificate", caCert);
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
        tmf.init(caKs);

        // client key and certificates are sent to server so it can authenticate
        // us
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(null, null);
        ks.setCertificateEntry("certificate", cert);
        ks.setKeyEntry("private-key", key.getPrivate(), password.toCharArray(), new java.security.cert.Certificate[] { cert });
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmf.init(ks, password.toCharArray());

        // finally, create SSL socket factory
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        context.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        return context.getSocketFactory();
    }
}
```

but when i run my program i have :

```
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

So i Tried to add my certificates to the Java trust store as suggested by many posts but i got the same error and i have absolutely no clue of what i am missing.

Comment: You haven't got the x.509 certificates worked out. You need to figure out what the MQTTBroker needs. Is 129.6.60.24 public or local or what? You should check with them and ask how to get a certificate. A useful certificate tutorial: http://www.baeldung.com/x-509-authentication-in-spring-security

Comment: The broker only needs the file brokerCertificate.crt that i have yo put in etc/mosquitto/certs and then specify this file in the mosquitto.conf file the adress is the adress of the computer on which is running the MQTT broker

Comment: Right, but look at the tutorial. If I understand correctly, the error is basically saying that the client cannot verify the server's certificate against any certificate authority in the client's truststore. In other words, the certificate coming from the server must be verified by a valid cert authority. By default, Java comes with a bunch, but if the server has its own private cert authority it won't be in the Java truststore. You have to get a copy of it from the server and create a truststore and add it to your client. Then your client will trust the server. Tutorial explains this.

Comment: yeah thats what i tried to do, i've even tried two different jdk with diferent trust stores i succeed to add certificates in the trust store but i don't know what's wrong i use  : `sudo keytool -import -file ./Workspace/Testbed/Dashboard/src/main/resources/brokerCertificate.crt -alias brokercert -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/cacerts`